# DBT macro is not returning anything in my dbt model

Tags: sql, macros, jinja2, dbt

I have created a macro that extracts the last_name from full_name and returns the last_name

```
{% macro parse_last_name(column_name) %}
    {% if column_name is none %}
        {{ return (column_name) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ return (column_name.split(',')[1]) }}
    {%endif%}
{% endmacro %}
```

this is called in my dbt model

```
select 
    
    {{parse_last_name('FULL_NAME')}} AS LAST_NAME

from <table_schema>
```

but the SQL compiled is:

```
select 
    
     AS LAST_NAME

from <target_schema>
```

so my macro is not returning anything.

I am running my model using `dbt run --select model_name.sql`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your macro:

1. You do not want to use the `return` keyword. `return` passes data back to the caller in the jinja context, but you're actually trying to write SQL code here
2. Data doesn't flow through the jinja context. When you write `column_name.split(',')[1]`, you're actually splitting the NAME of the column that you've passed in as a string, NOT the data from that column. In other words, your macro is equivalent to `"LAST_NAME".split(",")[1]`

You need your macro to return SQL to do this parsing for you. Something like this would work (on Snowflake):

```sql
{% macro parse_last_name(column_name) %}
    split_part({{ column_name }}, ',', 2)
{% endmacro %}
```

Note that this uses the SQL function `split_part`, so that when  your model is compiled, it becomes valid SQL:

```sql
select 
    
     split_part(LAST_NAME, ',', 2) AS LAST_NAME

from <target_schema>
```